# Auto computed column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to alter a table and add a column that is the sum of two other columns, and this column is auto computed when I add new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding this column to the table, I would recommend using a `View` to calculate the extra column, and read from that.

Here is a tutorial on how to create views here:

http://odetocode.com/Articles/299.aspx

---

Your view query would look something like:

```
 SELECT 
    ColumnA, ColumnB, (ColumnA+ColumnB) as ColumnC
  FROM 
    [TableName]
```

Comment: thx dude, after a long trying a found it!
the command is
`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_column AS (column1+column2)`
that's it dude
thx ;)

Comment: No worries @Neuvill, however I'm not certain the script you have posted fits your requirement. If any changes are made to the table, `my_column` values won't update.

Comment: @ Curt no iv try it, the syntax is correct, each time i insert a row the column `my_column` will be updated automaticaly, just delete the brackets in `(column1+column2)` i forgot to montion that

Answer (score 11):

The syntax for a computed column specification is as follows:

```
column-name AS formula
```

If the column values are to be stored within the database, the PERSISTED keyword should be added to the syntax, as follows:

```
column-name AS formula PERSISTED
```

You didn't mention an example, but if you wanted to add the column "sumOfAAndB" to calculate the Sum of A and B, your syntax looks like

```
ALTER TABLE tblExample ADD sumOfAAndB AS A + B
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would add the `PERSISTED` to your last `ALTER TABLE....`  statement there. Otherwise, the sum will be recalculated on every `SELECT` from that table - not very efficient...

Comment: Hey Marc, I've mentioned PERSISTED, but you are right; I should have told him that since the sum is deterministic he should do that. Even better would be if the Poster cosulted the manual to read up on how to do it right...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a view, but you may want to use a PERSISTED computed value if you don't want to incur the cost of computing  the value each time you access the view.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    a INT,
    b INT,
    operator CHAR,
    c AS CASE operator
        WHEN '+' THEN a+b
        WHEN '-' THEN a-b
        ELSE a*b
    END
    PERSISTED
) ;
```

See the [SQL docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) assuming you're using SQL Server of course.

Comment: i think that's not what im searching for... but its intersting, i think i will use it someday! thx dude!

Comment: It's basically the same as answer you marked as correct, just a slightly more complicated example.

Comment: the difirence is that we have to mention the operator.

Answer (score 1):

How to create computed column during creation of new table:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
       WORKORDERID INT NULL,
       ORDERQTY INT NULL,

       [ORDERVOL] AS CAST
       (
              CASE WHEN ORDERQTY < 10 THEN 'SINGLE DIGIT' WHEN ORDERQTY >=10 AND ORDERQTY < 100 THEN 'DOUBLE DIGIT' 
              WHEN ORDERQTY >=100 AND ORDERQTY < 1000 THEN 'THREE DIGIT' ELSE 'SUPER LARGE' END AS NVARCHAR(100)
       )

)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (1,1),(2,-1),(3,11)

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE table_name SET total = mark1+mark2+mark3;`

first think you can insert all the data into the table and then you can update the table like this form.

//i hop it's help to you

Comment: first think you can add the date in a column and then undate the table like this form.i hope it's help to you